# using a regex inside an HTML helper

Tags: regex, elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to add an HTML element attribute depending whether I'm passing an URL or not to an HTML helper.
I tried this in my `template.html.eex`:

```
<%= if Regex.match?(~r/www/, "@auxButton_linkURL") do %> target="_blank" <% else %><% end %>
```

I know that I'm close but this is not working (although no error, it simply just doesn't add the target attribute).
How to use it correctly?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thank you Andreas. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean to use the `@auxButton_linkURL` value from `conn.assigns`? If so you should use:

```
<%= if Regex.match?(~r/www/, @auxButton_linkURL) do %> target="_blank" <% else %><% end %>
```

Notice there are no quotes around `@auxButton_linkURL`. As an aside, variables by convention should use `snake_case` (`@aux_button_link_url`)

Comment: Yes, that's it. I though I've tried this and got an error but must have made something else wrong. Thank you Gazler.

Comment: Gazler, when the Regex doesn't match I get an error: `no function clause matching in Regex.match?/2`(that's why I though it wasn't working). This is not supposed to happen because I have an `ìf` `else`. Or is this something Regex related?

Comment: This probably happens because you are not passing a string to `Regex.match?` as the second argument. is `@auxButton_linkURL` nil?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there a way of making this not break with `nil`? Maybe using a default string + `@auxButton_linkURL`?

Comment: Ok, I've created a function in the view and I've used it in my template as the second argument and it's working. Nevertheless, I'm curious about the syntax to concatenate a string with `@auxButton_linkURL` as I think is more straightforward (but I couldn't do it...)

Comment: You can use `to_string` to ensure the value is a string.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!